WSO2 APIM - Too many open files
We are facing frequent issues with WSO2 APIM - 3.1.0 & IS - 5.10.0. Please find the below error message in the logs:
2024-07-21T23:57:18,620 [-] [PassThrough HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher Listener]  WARN PassThroughHttpMultiSSLListener System may be unstable: HTTPS ListeningIOReactor encountered a checked exception : Too many open files
java.io.IOException: Too many open files
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:252) ~[?:1.8.0_281]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultListeningIOReactor.processEvent(DefaultListeningIOReactor.java:170) [httpcore-nio_4.3.3.wso2v4.jar:?]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.DefaultListeningIOReactor.processEvents(DefaultListeningIOReactor.java:153) [httpcore-nio_4.3.3.wso2v4.jar:?]
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.execute(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:349) [httpcore-nio_4.3.3.wso2v4.jar:?]
at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager$1.run(PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager.java:536) [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v147.jar:?]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_281]

As per recommendations, we increased the soft limit to 65535 but still face the same issue. As per analysis, the application opens 1,000 to 1,500 files per hour and closes 2 to 3. This is forcing us to restart services every three days.
Some of the system parameters are as below:
file-max value is 2097152
Soft limit and Hard limit 65535 
Soft Proc and Hard Proc 20000
JVM - -Xms4096m -Xmx4096m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m

Any assistance would be of great help. Thank you!
Increased the soft limit

What is your JDK version? And do you see any High CPU utilization when running the API Manager in your environment?

Let's use cat /proc//limits command to check whether the configured file limits have been applied to the running process. Depending on the OS flavor and how you run the WSO2 server, globally configured limits are not getting applied and there are some specific ways to do that. if the process has the configured limits, then can you share the output of lsof -a -d ^mem -d ^cwd -d ^rtd -d ^txt -d ^DEL -p  command so that we can check the opened files
